# NSTextField lags when changing frame

Tags: cocoa

I am building my first application for osx and have run into trouble when i try to change the frame of a NSTextField.

I am trying to change the frame of the text field inside an animation (so close to 60 fps) and it works when my window is really small and the textfield is empty. But when i enter a lot of text into the text field or just make it much bigger the animation will lagg horribly. This can also be seen when i resize the window containing the text field.

Resizing the window in the TextEdit application works at close to 60 fps so i would like some help to achieve similar performance.

Currently i do something similar to below on every frame of the animation.

```
NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height);
self.textField.frame = rect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i got some advice to use NSTextView instead of NSTextField and it solved most of my issues.